# Android UI vs Opengl ES 2 UI

Tags: android, c++, user-interface, opengl-es-2.0

this question is more for looking advices

I've developed an almost full user interface in pure c++ and opengl es 2, currently I'm developing that the click/touch events be propagate as in HTML, I can't remember why I decided do a UI in opengl, but now I realize that I'm reinventing the wheel.

so currently I have many "elements", buttons, containers, scrolls, pictures, animated pictures, borders, text, drag-drop's, I can set easily where I want each element, set sounds, and I really don't know how fast and effective it is right now, but I've maked all the fast and memory effective that I can, and I planning to use multi-threading in the future. And my goal is to approach a system like html.

And now that I'm looking for how to implement my UI in native Android (java), I realized that I was in the correct way, all the properties and methods all the structure I'm implementing in c++ and opengl is almost the same as in android, even I think my implementation is easier to use the images and sounds because I've automatized all and I can put it in the assets folder, and in the code only put the name of the file and the program returns it, with and effective memory managment.

the current elements are elements that I need for a game interface, so if I need other kind of element I'd have to write it, but right now, I have all elements that I need, I think so.

maybe my code in c++ is faster than java.

but even with all this, I know I have a lot to do to have a full UI, so can you give some advices or experience, advantages, disadvantages, it worth to continue with the UI, or better learn (beacuse I just know a llitle bit of UI Android) UI Android, modify all my game for use the new arquitecture/system, What do you think?

Comment: Better learn ..open gl es has got more then what you might have imagined